# Condición Adn para Sqlite en Android Studio

Tags: android, sql

Pretendo agregar una condición con AND ejemplo:

```
String CODIGO =et_codigo.getText().toString();
String NOMBRE =et_nombre.getText().toString();


Cursor fila = Basededatos.rawQuery
                ("select codigo,nombre,direccion from usuarios where 
codigo=? AND nombre=?"+ CODIGO + NOMBRE,null);
```

Me aparece **Error al emular la aplicación**

Comment: Que tal, bienvenido... Por favor, antes que nada date una vuelta por [ask]...  Así mismo solicitarte más información, como por ejemplo más código, y el log de la aplicación... Y de paso edita las etiquetas que no nos orienta sobre qué estas trabajando...

Answer (score 0):

¿No sería lo siguiente?:

```
Cursor fila = Basededatos.rawQuery ("select codigo,nombre,direccion from usuarios where codigo='" + CODIGO + "' AND nombre='" + NOMBRE + "'",null)
```

Comment: Parece que el usuario quiere utilizar sentencias preparadas (tiene puestos ? donde deberían ir los valores). Aparte, esta sugerencia, aunque podría ser válida, es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse.